# Turn off events for specific item in selection

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

Let's say I have something like this:

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', 'button', doSomething);
```

Obviously I want all buttons to `doSomething()` on click. Now let's say I want one of those buttons to NOT do that, but do something else.

```
$('#mydiv').off('click', '.specialclass button');
```

This does not work, but I need it to. Is there a way to achieve this? I'd very much prefer not to have to wire up each button individually.

This part of the [`.off()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/)  is what's killing me:

> To remove specific delegated event handlers, provide a selector argument. The selector string must exactly match the one passed to .on() when the event handler was attached.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/A6Ew3/) demoing what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the jQuery pseudo-selector `:not()` to exclude a search result, it is document [here](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', 'button:not(.specialclass)', doSomething);
```

Then you could just specify the specific case seperatly:

```
$('.specialclass').on('click', function() { console.log('sup'; });
```

---

You can also use unbind to turn off events in jQuery.

```
$('div').unbind('click');​
```

While not deprecated, according to the docs:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements

Comment: this is ok, but assume that the initial setting is in a module and the `.off` will be in another module. The first module doesn't know what classes will be in the second module

Comment: neither of these solutions [work](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/Mu67B/), unfortunately.

Comment: @Jason is there a reason you are using the div to handle the events instead of the button: http://jsfiddle.net/CuNYV/

Comment: yes, i bind all of my events to the container because they are inserted dynamically

Comment: it just seems so stupidly inflexible. why make it so that if i want to turn off an event i have to have the EXACT selector used to turn it on? why can't having an equivalent selector that has the exact same element be enough? grrrrrrr

Comment: i agree, it is puzzling. It doesn't look possible to have dynamically selected events with exclusion.